# Но ты как будто за семью замками. Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

*Но ты как будто за семью замками.* Нужна ли здесь запятая?

Answer (score 3):

Но ты **как будто за семью замками**.

Сравнить: Но ты за семью замками.

Эллиптическое предложение (подлежащее - обстоятельство),  союз КАК БУДТО относится к обстоятельству, нет знаков препинания.

Answer (score 0):

***Но ты как будто за семью замками.***

Запятая не ставится, так как **"за семью замками" - сказуемое**. Именной частью сказуемого могут быть фразеологизированные сочетания именного типа. ***Ты (какая?) за семью замками***. Между подлежащим и сказуемым, связанными  союзом или частицей, запятая **не ставится.**

Comment: Нет, здесь фразеологизм  "за  семью замками"  означает не прилагательное, потому что  есть "как будто".Ср. ты как будто неприступная, что-то не по - русски) Это иноск." взаперти, под охраной, вдали от света". Используется в качестве наречной группы, значит, обстоятельство. Предложение действительно эллиптическое.